# Pytest tests packaged with PyInstaller not being collected

Tags: python-2.7, automated-tests, pytest, pyinstaller

I have this problem, I've created a test suite comprised of PyTest tests, they are packaged in a class, example below:

```
class TestExecutor(object):
     @classmethod
     def setup_class(cls):
         pass
     def test_testuiteStructure(self):
         pass
```

i also created in the same .py file the following code to call the pytest execution:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":       
    pytest.main()
```

The behavior I see when i execute in terminal python tests.py is fine.
the problem starts when i package the file using PyInstaller into an executable .exe file ( i need this to stream line the execution process since i run the tests on multiple machines)
when I execute the created .exe file i get the following message:

```
 ============================= test session starts ==================
 platform win32 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- 
 ....
 ....
 ....
 collected 0 items
```

Meaning there are no tests, anyone has any idea how i can solve it ?

Comment: Don't package the tests with Pyinstaller, pytest needs source code to work with.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was thinking, is there a way around it ? i want to reduce the overhead of pulling the code from Git and and installing Python on each of the machines where i want to run the tests.

Comment: Hmm, you could try bundling `pytest` itself into a single executable. As for Git, you can do a shallow clone with `--depth=1` that omits pulling the commit history, this speeds up the cloning a lot.

Comment: Once again , thanks for your answer, could you possibly share a way to bundle pytest ? i've already importing it in the  .py file which i'm converting to the executable , also that file contains all the test and pytest.main() invocation

Comment: Thinking about it bit more, maybe you are running into an XY problem. If you are solving a task of running same set of tests against multiple hosts, it may be more wise to use `pytest-xdist`, you can configure it to start the test run on master host which executes the tests on all registered slaves. An example for that can found [here](https://holgerkrekel.net/2013/11/12/running-tests-against-multiple-devicesresources-in-parallel/).

Comment: thanks will have a look at, though it's not quite my problem , mine is a bit more basic than that

Comment: Very relevant: "Freezing pytest", https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html?highlight=pyinstaller#freezing-pytest

Comment: Also relevant: "Interpreting cmdline arguments as Python packages", https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/pythoncollection.html#interpreting-cmdline-arguments-as-python-packages